# Find the unit digit of $2124^{392}+3143^{394}*7177^{392}-8818^{394}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I do here is I find the remainder of each parcel in mod 10 and then do the maths and mod 10 again:

$2124^{392} \equiv 4^{392} \pmod{10}$

$$4^1 \equiv 4 \pmod{10} \\
4^2 \equiv 6  \\
4^3 \equiv 4 \\
4^4 \equiv 6 \\
(...)$$

Then I do $392 \pmod{2}$. Problem is that here, it's zero. If it were 1 or 2, the remainder would be either 4 or 6. How do I solve it this way?

Comment: You find the units digit of each term, and then it is easy. As you found, $2124^{392}\equiv6\pmod{10}$, $3143^{394}\equiv9\pmod{10}$, $7177^{392}\equiv1\pmod{10}$, $8818^{394}\equiv4\pmod{10}$. So, the last digit is also the last digit of $$6+9\cdot1 -4=11\equiv\color{red}1\pmod{10}$$

Comment: reminder can't be $2$,  since we are doing $\pmod{2}$, when it's zero, it means the reminder is $6$

Answer (score 1):

$4^1\equiv 4$
$4^2\equiv 6$
$4^3\equiv 4$
$\vdots$

When the exponent is odd, the remainder is $4$.
When the exponent is even the remainder is $6$.

$0$ is even and so is $392$, thus $4^{392}\equiv 6\pmod{10}$

---

As an alternative notice that $6^k\equiv 6\pmod{10}$,
so $4^{392} = 16^{196}\equiv 6\pmod{10}$

Answer (score 0):

Using Newton's  binomial formula,
$$4^{392}=(10-6)^{392} $$
$$=6^{392} \mod 10 =6 \mod 10$$
Since $$6^2 = 6\mod 10$$

For the second and the third , $ 3$ and $ 7$ are coprime with $ 10$ so by Euler's  Theorem

$$3^{\phi(10)}=1 \mod(10) =3^4$$
and
$$7^4 = 1 \mod 10$$

For example

$$3^{394}=3^{98.4+2}=9 \mod 10$$

For the last one, observe that
$$2^5 = 2 \mod 10$$
then
$$8^5= 2^{3.5}=2^3=8 \mod 10$$
thus
$$8^{394}=8^{78.5+4}=8^{78+4}=8^{16.5+2}=8^{16+2}=8^{3.5+3}=8^6$$
$$=8^{5+1}=8^2=4 \mod 10$$

Answer (score 0):

For the middle term note that $3\times 7=21\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

Thus $3143^{394}\times 7177^{392}\equiv 1^{392}\times 3143^2\equiv 3^2\equiv 9\pmod{10}$ without much calculation.